# Idiom for long tuple unpacking

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

Scenario: you have a long tuple as a result of a SQL query and want to unpack it into individual values. What's the best way to do that while conforming to PEP8? So far I have these three options:

1. single assignment, use backslash to split to multiple lines

   ```
   person_id, first_name, last_name, email, \
       birth_date, graduation_year, home_street, \
       home_city, home_zip, mail_street, mail_city, \
       mail_zip = row
   ```
2. single assignment, group left-hand side in parantheses and break lines without a backslash

   ```
   (person_id, first_name, last_name, email,
       birth_date, graduation_year, home_street,
       home_city, home_zip, mail_street, mail_city,
       mail_zip) = row
   ```
3. split into multiple assignments, each fitting into a single line

   ```
   person_id, first_name, last_name, email = row[0:4]
   birth_date, graduation_year, home_street = row[4:7]
   home_city, home_zip, mail_street, mail_city = row[7:11]
   mail_zip = row[11]
   ```

Which of the three options is the best? Is there anything better?

Comment: Opinion based. I don't like the solution with the backslash at the end of a line because the code will break if you have an invisible character (e.g. space) after it. For me, the second version is the way to go.

Comment: Have you considered a single [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of separate names?

Comment: @Matthias He does ask "while conforming to PEP-8", and PEP-8 is pretty explicit about which to use.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap it into a dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why did you vote to close this question as primarily opinion-based? The author of the question is not asking about unqualified preference, but he is asking whether any given approaches have certain advantages or disadvantages, and the answer to that is not subjective at all. The very first comment above is already a contradiction: Matthias says "Opinion based", only to follow up by providing an objective disadvantage of the backslash method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Anwering your question "Which of the three options is the best?"

[pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) states:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

This Means the second one is preferred over the first one. The third one is fine conforming pep8 as well, though personally wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 The third is far less efficient, requiring many more byte codes to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 8):

To answer *"is there anything better"*, I would suggest that a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) allows you to access the individual data items with minimal fuss:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Person = namedtuple("Person", ['person_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
                                   'email', 'birth_date', 'graduation_year', 
                                   'home_street', 'home_city', 'home_zip', 
                                   'mail_street', 'mail_city', 'mail_zip'])
>>> row = range(12) # dummy data
>>> p = Person(*row) # unpack tuple into namedtuple
>>> p
Person(person_id=0, first_name=1, last_name=2, email=3, birth_date=4, graduation_year=5, home_street=6, home_city=7, home_zip=8, mail_street=9, mail_city=10, mail_zip=11)
>>> p.birth_date
4
```

This means you access attributes, rather than separate names, but is lighter-weight than building a class, keeps all of the data from your query together and exposes the values through sensible names.

Comment: This looks fine as long as you have to do this multiple times for the same sequence of attributes. However, if you know you won't unpack such row in more than one place, this is probably too heavyweight (instead of a single or a few assignments, you have to import a collection, define a named tuple etc. just for a single unpacking).

Comment: @koniiiik per the docs, `namedtuple`s *"require no more memory than regular tuples"*. Defining the container is the same length as your current unpacking, so you're only adding two lines (`import` and unpack). If you're certain you'd only ever use it once, though, you may be right.

Comment: Well, at the very least, it consists of more not entirely trivial steps which may make it less obvious what is going on. But again, depends on the exact situation.